# How to sort an alphanumeric array in perl?

Tags: perl

I have an alphanumeric  array called

```
my @array1= (gee0,gee1,gee7,gee10,gee12,gee20,gee24,gee15,gee8,gee47);
```

How can I sort the above alphanumeric array?

Comment: What result do you expect? Make [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: BTW your code is wrong. See the result `perl -MData::Dumper -e'my @array1= {"gee0",gee1,gee7,gee10,gee12,gee20,gee24,gee15,gee8,gee47};print Dumper(\@array1)'`. Do you expect answers when you don't even bother to run one line of code and check if it does what you expect?

Comment: Thanks for you reply.....sorry for posting wrong code ...I have corrected the code

Comment: Always `use strict;` and  `use warnings;`. Your code is still wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can write any sort of comparison code using the $a and $b variables into the sort command. For example using the alphanumeric comparative operator:

```
my @sorted_array = sort {
  $a <=> $b
} @array1;
```

This will not work with the strings as you have them. If they all contain the same prefix, you can strip that before the comparison like:

```
my @sorted_array = sort {
  my ($anum) = ($a =~ /\w(\d+)$/);
  my ($bnum) = ($b =~ /\w(\d+)$/);
  $anum <=> $bnum
} @array1;
```

Of course, this would be stripping it on every comparison. In case the array would be large, you want to pre-strip it like this:

```
my @sorted_array =  map { 
  $_->[0]
} sort {
  $a->[1] <=> $b->[1]
} map {
  [$_,($_ =~ /(\d+)$/)]
} @array1;
```

This basically creates a new array where each element is a pair of a sortable key and the original value and after sorting them by the key, you strip the key and just present the values. This technique is called [Schwartzian Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)

Comment: Thanks you ...for the help .I got the idea .

Comment: Schwartzian is way overkill for this situation, IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the code. I've got right-left dyslexia, sometimes I transpose things left to right. Meant to put the index left and put it right.

Comment: huh, doesn't using the ST slow things down here? If using ST does help, you'd be better off using `map substr($_, 4), sort map pack('N', /(\d+)/).$_, @data`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the Schwartzian Transform is to create a new array of the transformed values that you want to sort by, sort that array's *indices*, and use the sorted indices to reorder the original data as an array slice.

It loks like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array   = qw/ gee0 gee1 gee7 gee10 gee12 gee20 gee24 gee15 gee8 gee47 /;
my @values  = map /(\d+)/, @array;
my @indices = sort { $values[$a] <=> $values[$b] } 0 .. $#values;

print "$array[$_]\n" for @indices;
```

**output**

```
gee0
gee1
gee7
gee8
gee10
gee12
gee15
gee20
gee24
gee47
```

Comment: Are you aware that this is in essence the Schwartzian Transform, just redrawn in a different syntax and with one extra step? Simply instead of [n,2] 2-dimensional array, you use 2 [n] 1-dimensional arrays. Then tie them through the index.

Comment: @JiriKlouda: Are you aware that an ordinary sort operation is in essence the *Schwartzian Transform*, just written in a different syntax that saves memory by recalculating the sort function only when it is needed instead of caching it alongside the original data?

Comment: That is not the case. You cannot make an isomorphism mapping the memory requirement, computational difficulty and number of steps between Schwartz and ordinary sort, but you can make an isomorphism mapping your solution onto Schwatzian Transform. That is how we compare two things in mathematics. :)

Comment: @JiriKlouda: I don't see how your isomorphism is a useful comparison when a normal `sort` and a *ST* both create a new sorted list of the original data whereas this technique creates just a list of indices. Note that multiple such lists can be created which reflect the data sorted in different orders, without the need to duplicate the data in the original array, each element of which could be large. In case you were'nt understanding properly I have changed the final `print` statement so that it iterates over the list of indices instead of building a separate array slice.

Comment: You are right that there is no copy of the original values and that at 2nd and further index or in case of read only original data, or even data on disk, your method would be preferable to create a new sorted index.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the simplest solution, it's:

```
use Sort::Key::Natural qw( natsort );

my @sorted = natsort @data;
```

If you're looking for the fastest solution, it's:

```
use Sort::Key::Natural qw( natsort );

my @sorted = natsort @data;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response .what is the meaning of "natsort" here?

Comment: `natsort @data` is a subroutine call.